What's the difference between $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$ and $\mathbb{F}(x)$?
I have been reading the first chapter of Field and Galois Theory written by Patrick Morandi recently. And he often takes examples like rational function field $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ in the book. I don't understand why he uses $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$ rather than $\mathbb{F}(x)$, $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristic $0$? Is $\mathbb{F}_p(x)/\mathbb{F}_p$ an algebraic extension?

Please do not answer in the comments.

This is a classical approach to Galois theory. The typical examples, and primary motivation, for Galois theory are finite extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$, i.e. number fields.
It turns out that a natural generalisation of number fields are what are called global fields, and one can show that global fields are exactly number fields AND finite extensions of function fields over finite fields $\Bbb{F}_q(x)$.
In other words, extensions of $\Bbb{F}_q(x)$ share many of the same properties of number fields, and they can to a good extent be treated simultaneously. Note that this is not the case for function fields over characteristic $0$ fields.
If one delves a bit into number theory, it turns out that many theorems are actually easier to prove over function fields over finite fields than over number fields, and can often work as a prototype. Thus, it is a great idea to become familiar with these fields.
